# Slider not working the first time

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, home, slider

I have an slider in my home web  with the next and prev button to see the images. If I go to the home, the slider appears with a big height and all the images are displayed in a lot of rows.

However, If I update the page, the slider appears correctly, with a row with only 3-4 little images and the buttons.

What is the problem? There aren't js errors in the firefox or chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It's a caching problem. Let Magento generate the files the first time and then you'll be fine. It isn't anything to worry about as long as it works afterwards.

Whoever hits the page the first time will have that problem, but it will not happen for everyone the first time... you just need to generate it and it won't happen at all.

Try it in another browser and it should load properly, otherwise I'm wrong.

Comment: Ahh ok!!  How can I do that?

Comment: Which bit, comrade? You generate the static files simply by visiting the page and it loading. :)